# Looking for a function with parameters and output on the unit interval...

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a function $f(x, y)$ with both parameters on the interval $[0,1]$ such that half of all possible values of $x$ are $<y$, and half are $>y$.

For instance, if I apply an $x$ of $0.25$, I want the function $f(y)$ it produces to be:

- $<0.25$ if $y<0.5$
- $>0.25$ if $y>0.5$
- $=0.25$ if $y=0.5$

Output values should also fall on the interval $[0,1]$.

A smooth function would be best (ideally the graph of any $f(y)$ would be diagonally symmetrical), but I'm also looking for something that's easy to compute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be what you want but, if not, please clarify what you require.

Let $f(x,y)=2xy$ if $y\le 0.5$ and $f(x,y)=1-2(1-x)(1-y)$ if $y>0.5$ then

$f(x,y)<x$ if $y<0.5$,

$f(x,y)>x$ if $y>0.5$,

$f(x,y)=x$ if $y=0.5$.

A smooth function that might be of interest is

$f(x,y)=0$ if $xy=0$ and, otherwise, $f(x,y)=y^{-\log_2(x)}.$

Comment: That's a function that does satisfy the criteria, but it's not what I would ideally want, since the change of slope is quite abrupt. I've been playing around with $f(x, y) = 1-(1-y^x)^{(1/x)}$ since it has pretty much the ideal shape, but I can't get it to fit the requirements I outlined above.

Comment: (As an aside, I've also been looking into applying e.g. $arctanh$ to $x$ beforehand for that equation but it doesn't quite work.)

Comment: I've added a smooth function that looks good for $0<x<1$.

Comment: Thank you! That looks close to ideal.